# Splice and var x={}

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

This works:

```
var y=["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
y.splice(0,1);
document.write(y);
```

It gives (predictably): Orange,Apple,Mango

This is also OK:

```
var z={};
z[32]="Help";
z[14]="Go";
```

But this doesn't work:

```
z.splice(32,1);
```

The error message in Firebug is:

> Error: z.splice is not a function ...

There's clearly a rule I don't know about. What is it, and how does one splice out something like z[32]?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

y is an array and z is an object.

You can't use a function in the array prototype in an object.

```
var z=[];
z[32]="Help";
z[14]="Go";

z.splice(32,1);
```

Will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring `z` as an object.  `splice` is an array function.  Try:

```
var z = [];
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove an element from an object use:

```
var z={};
z[32]="Help";
z[14]="Go";
delete z[32];
```

otherwise you will need to use an array.